# Thread function takes x as argument; a function outside thread with x.something() updates x in thread, but an approach using 'global x' doesn't. Why?

Tags: python, global-variables

Consider the following example:

```
import time
import threading

queue_variable = []

def thread_fn(queue_argument):
    while True:
        for i,e  in enumerate(queue_argument):
            print(str(i)+". item: " + str(e))
        time.sleep(5)

def add_to_queue(*args):
    global queue_variable
    queue_variable = [*queue, *args]

x = threading.Thread(target=thread_fn, args=(queue_variable,), daemon=True)
x.start()
```

Running `add_to_queue(1,2,3)` will update the queue variable, but not the one within the thread. Rewriting `add_to_queue` using instead a `queue.append()` approach with no global variable, however, will effect the desired behaviour.

What is the explanation behind this? I would have expected globalizing the scope of a variable to do precisely this, but we see that isn't the case.

Comment: Why would it? `queue` and `queue_variable` are two entirely separate variables.

Comment: @chepner very sorry, I had made a mistake writing the post. I meant to only use queue_variable

Comment: `queue_variable = [*queue, *args]` set the thing named `queue_variable` inside `add_to_queue()` to a completely new reference even though it originally referenced the `global queue_variable`.  `append()` works though because the reference to the global thing is not clobbered, but instead used.

Comment: `thread_fn`, on the other hand, does *not* access the global name `queue_variable`; it has its *own* reference to that list which is not affected by *assignments* to the global name.

Comment: thanks for the comments, that made it clearer